# How to properly export and process data from editable table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have followed up an editable table from https://codepen.io/ashblue/pen/mCtuA

The above editable field works perfect for me but I'm trying to clone this table I'm not able to export it's data properly, here is the code

```js
var $TABLE = $('#table');
var $BTN = $('#export-btn');
var $EXPORT = $('#export');

$('.table-add').click(function () {
  var $clone = $TABLE.find('tr.hide').clone(true).removeClass('hide table-line');
  $TABLE.find('table').append($clone);
});

$('.table-remove').click(function () {
  $(this).parents('tr').detach();
});

$('.table-up').click(function () {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  if ($row.index() === 1) return; // Don't go above the header
  $row.prev().before($row.get(0));
});

$('.table-down').click(function () {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  $row.next().after($row.get(0));
});

// A few jQuery helpers for exporting only
jQuery.fn.pop = [].pop;
jQuery.fn.shift = [].shift;

$BTN.click(function () {
  var $rows = $TABLE.find('tr:not(:hidden)');
  var headers = [];
  var data = [];
  
  // Get the headers (add special header logic here)
  $($rows.shift()).find('th:not(:empty)').each(function () {
    headers.push($(this).text().toLowerCase());
  });
  
  // Turn all existing rows into a loopable array
  $rows.each(function () {
    var $td = $(this).find('td');
    var h = {};
    
    // Use the headers from earlier to name our hash keys
    headers.forEach(function (header, i) {
      h[header] = $td.eq(i).text();   
    });
    
    data.push(h);
  });
  
  // Output the result
  $EXPORT.text(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

```css
@import "compass/css3";

.table-editable {
  position: relative;
  
  .glyphicon {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

.table-remove {
  color: #700;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  &:hover {
    color: #f00;
  }
}

.table-up, .table-down {
  color: #007;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  &:hover {
    color: #00f;
  }
}

.table-add {
  color: #070;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 0;
  
  &:hover {
    color: #0b0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>HTML5 Editable Table</h1>
  <p>Through the powers of <strong>contenteditable</strong> and some simple jQuery you can easily create a custom editable table. No need for a robust JavaScript library anymore these days.</p>
  
  <ul>
    <li>An editable table that exports a hash array. Dynamically compiles rows from headers</li> 
    <li>Simple / powerful features such as add row, remove row, move row up/down.</li>
  </ul>
  
  <div id="table" class="table-editable">
    <span class="table-add glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true">Stir Fry</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-up glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
          <span class="table-down glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- This is our clonable table line -->
      <tr class="hide">
        <td contenteditable="true">1</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">2</td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-up glyyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
          <span class="table-down glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  
  <button id="export-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Export Data</button>
  <p id="export"></p>
  
  <hr><span class="table-add glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true">Stir Fry</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">stir-fry</td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-up glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
          <span class="table-down glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- This is our clonable table line -->
      <tr class="hide">
        <td contenteditable="true">1</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">2</td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-up glyyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
          <span class="table-down glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  
  <button id="export-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Export Data</button>
  <p id="export"></p>
</div>
```

Now the problem arises that I'm unable to differentiate from which cloned part data is coming i need to process all the data through php and store it properly in database

Comment: I don't really understand your question here. Is that when you press `Export Data` button I don't get any information or is it about you not getting the same results as the codepen example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has to do with duplicate IDs in your markup.  Remember, IDs must be unique.  That being said, you'll need to update your JS a little to account for the appropriate element being selected.

Look at traversing the DOM with `.parent()`, .`parents()`, etc and keep in mind what `this` is referring to.  Give it a crack and I can help you out further if you need it.